# C# [WebMethod] is not hitting when Content-Type ''application/Json" is not provided

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, json, iframe

I have created a C# WebMethod

```
  [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static HttpResponseMessage GetPageHtml(string file, int page)
    {}
```

I am able to call it and it works fine using Ajax, angular, Postman when i add header Content-Type :  'application/Json'. Here is the sample HTTP request which is working fine.

```
$http({
            url: 'default.aspx/GetPageHtml?file=' + JSON.stringify(selectedFile) + '&page=' + itemNumber,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            data:''
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response.d;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });
```

But when i call the same method as a for iframe ng-src it is not working.

```
<iframe ng-src="default.aspx/GetPageHtml?file=candy.pdf&page=1" style="height: 150px;"></iframe>
```

I inspected this Http call over Google Chrome's Developers tools and found that Content-Type is 'text/html' there, that is why it is not hitting my WebMethod. Please see this screenshot. 
[Iframe ng-src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J356C.png)

I investigated a lot over Google and Stackoverflow, but i could not find a reason why i need to provide Content-Type : 'application/json' to call my WebMethod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I further investigated my question and tried to find other ways around, I came up with a solution. I created a new WebForm named `GetDocumentHtml.aspx` and in its `Page_Load` Method i am doing operation which i was previously doing in `GetPageHtml` `WebMethod`.

Now in `iframe` `ng-src` i am providing this URL

`/GetDocumentHtml.aspx?file=calibre.docx&page=1`

Instead of

`default.aspx/GetPageHtml?file=candy.pdf&page=1`

In Page_Load Method i am using following code to get URL parameters

```
var file = GetValueFromQueryString("file");
var page =Convert.ToInt32(GetValueFromQueryString("page"));
```

GetValueFromQueryString Method

```
 private String GetValueFromQueryString(String value)
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.QueryString[value].ToString();

        }
        catch (System.Exception exp)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

I hope this information will be helpful for someone. Thanks.